# Getting Compile Time error in reduceGroup function of Dataset in scala

Tags: scala, dataset

I am trying to reduce a group in Scala.
Below is my code:

```
 val record = file.map(rec => (rec.state,rec.gender,rec.aadharGenerated.toInt)).groupByKey(_._1)
    .reduceGroups((a,b)=>{
    var total = a._3 + b._3
    var mTotal = if(a._2.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("m")) {(a._3.toInt + b._3.toInt)}
    (a._1,total.toString(),mTotal)
    }).collect
```

In second last line I am getting compile time error "type mismatch; found : AnyVal required: Int"

The third parameter is supposed to be int. And the value I am adding are int already.
I am new to Scala, any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `if` as an expression without an `else` for your `mTotal` variable. The return type of an `if` is the nearest common super type of both the *success* block and the *else* block.

If you don't provide an `else` block, Scala will **assume**:

```
else ()
```

`()` is the value of `Unit`. So, for `mTotal` to be an `Int`, you need to provide a fallback value with an `else` block.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your data, but your assertion:

> The third parameter is supposed to be int.

doesn't hold. What if `a._2.trim().equalsIgnoreCase ("m")` evaluates to false?

```
scala> var mTotal = if ("a".equalsIgnoreCase("m")) {7} 
mTotal: AnyVal = ()
```